# Concise C# code for gathering several properties with a non-null value into a collection?

Tags: c#, collections, properties, nullable

A fairly basic problem for a change. Given a class such as this:

```
public class X
{
    public T A;
    public T B;
    public T C;
    ...

    // (other fields, properties, and methods are not of interest here)
}
```

I am looking for a concise way to code a method that will return all `A`, `B`, `C`, `...` that are not null in an enumerable collection. (Assume that declaring these fields as an array is not an option.)

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullABCs(this X x)
{
    // ?
}
```

The obvious implementation of this method would be:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullABCs(this X x)
{
    var resultSet = new List<T>();

    if (x.A != null) resultSet.Add(x.A);
    if (x.B != null) resultSet.Add(x.B);
    if (x.C != null) resultSet.Add(x.C);
    ...

    return resultSet;
}
```

What's bothering me here in particular is that the code looks verbose and repetitive, and that I don't know the initial `List` capacity in advance.

It's my hope that there is a more clever way, probably something involving the `??` operator? Any ideas?

---

### Note about the chosen answer:

I finally went for a mix of both [Bryan Watts'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893481/concise-c-code-for-gathering-several-properties-with-a-non-null-value-into-a-col/2893514#2893514) and [dtb's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893481/concise-c-code-for-gathering-several-properties-with-a-non-null-value-into-a-col/2893488#2893488) answers that allows for a clear separation of defining the set of properties `A`,`B`,`C`,`...` and the filtering of the non-null subset:

**(1) Definition of the set of included fields/properties:**

```
IEnumerable<T> AllABCs(this X x)
{
    return new[] { x.A, x.B, x.C, ... };
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
IEnumerable<T> AllABCs(this X x)
{
    yield return x.A;
    yield return x.B;
    yield return x.C;
    ...
    yield break;
}
```

**(2) Returning only non-null values:**

```
IEnumerable<T> ThatAreNotNull(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.Where(item => item != null);
}

IEnumerable<T> AllNonNullABCs(this X x)
{
    return AllABCs().ThatAreNotNull();
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //     goal reached; it won't get shorter and clearer than this, IMO!
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullAs(this X x)
{
    return new[] { x.A, x.B, x.C }.Where(t => t != null);
}
```

Comment: Accepted because your answer is so wonderfully short and clear. Perhaps for a large number of properties, a solution involving `yield` would be preferable because of a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword to create an enumerable that returns the elements directly instead of populating a list:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullAs(this X x)
{
    if (x.A != null) yield return x.A;
    if (x.B != null) yield return x.B;
    if (x.C != null) yield return x.C;
    ...
}
```

To get rid of the null checks, you could write a method that returns all values, and filter the result:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllAs(this X x)
{
    yield return x.A;
    yield return x.B;
    yield return x.C;
    ...
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullAs(this X x)
{
    return x.GetAllAs().Where(y => y != null);
}
```

Comment: Very nice (the combination of `yield` and `.Where` LINQ query)! That's the kind of code improvement I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to the rescue!

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullAs(this X x)
{
    return from pi in x.GetType().GetProperties()
           let val = pi.GetValue(x, null)
           where val != null
           select (T) val;
}
```

You might also want to add a check that the value is of type `T`, but I'm not sure whether tha's an issue for you.

Comment: This sacrifices performance to a very large degree simply not to have to specify each property.

Comment: Yes, but the "..." after `A`, `B`, `C`, implies there are more than just three properties. This will work for any number of properties.

Comment: Also this will loop though ALL properties. If you have specific ones that should not be part of this youre doomed.

Comment: The requirement was "code a method that will return all A, B, C, ... that are not null in an enumerable collection" - that's exactly what this method does. There were no requirements on performance, no requirements on only a specific subset. Why write 15 lines of code for 15 properties when 4 will suffice?

Comment: Actually, there might be other fields/properties that should not be included; that's why I put the *"other fields, properties, ... not of interest"* bit in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should have used an array or other collection type when defining your class:

```
public class X
{
    public T[] ABC = new T[3];
    ...
}
```

Then it becomes trivial:

```
return ABC.Where(x => x != null);
```

Comment: As I said, that's not an option. I only named the fields `A`,`B`,`C`,`...` for demonstration purposes, but in my real class, they'd have more distinct names that can't and shouldn't be subsumed in an array.

Comment: @stakx: Oh I missed that bit. But note that you can still use this same technique even if you can't change the class by creating the array from scratch each time you need it. Which is what the answer you've accepted does.

Comment: (That's right. I first thought a `yield` solution would be best, but after seeing how very brief an array-based solution can be, I changed my mind.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator block for this, though it's not much less verbose.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullAs(this X x)
{
    if(x.A != null) yield return x.A;
    if(x.B != null) yield return x.B;
    if(x.C != null) yield return x.C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a hybrid of some of the other answers.  Use `yield` to return the properties, but then use the `.Where` LINQ extension method to filter out the nulls.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllNonNullAs(this X x)
{
    return this.Add(X.A, X.B, X.C);
}

private List<T> Add(params X[] items)
{
   var result = new List<T>();
   foreach(var item in items)
   {
       if(item != null)
       {
           result.Add(item);
       }
   }
}
```